# Run gimp from console

Tags: windows, gimp

I am a windows user and want to run gimp from the console as seen [HERE](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).  On Windows this means putting the program on your path.  I used:

```
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin
```

And....

```
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.8.exe
C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.8.exe
```

but when I type:

```
gimp --version
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\trinker>gimp --version
'gimp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I make Windows detect gimp from the command line so that I can run batches?  Unfortunately typing `gimp` + `path` results in searches related to the path creating in gimp.

I can run the gui of gimp fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In console, type:

```
PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin"
```

Then hit

```
gimp-2.8 --version
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have a `gimp.exe` in the `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin` directory,  you will need to type something like:

```
gimp-2.8.exe --version
```

Take a look [here](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html) for some other recommendations about batch usage under windows.

Answer (score 1):

After you find your proper path, did you try gimp-console-2.8.exe (or whatever your version is)? I found mine under the Gimp 2/bin/ path.

Answer (score -4):

One image speak more than thousand word

[image]

Comment: It really doesn't. Stack Overflow is not for pictures of text.

Comment: Also, posted years after the other answers and contributed nothing new.